# RestSharp XML Deserialization Setting Values to Null

Tags: c#, xml, restsharp

The XML serializer of the RestSharp request is set to DotNetXmlSerializer.

I make the following REST call with RestSharp :

```
var response = restClient.Execute<TokenReponse>(request);
```

This call yields the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lsvt_apiResult 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <result>true</result>
    <data xsi:type="xsd:string">TokenStringValueHere</data>
</lsvt_apiResult>
```

TokenResponse is the following C# class:

```
 internal class TokenReponse
 {
    [XmlElement("result")]
    public string Result { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("data")]
    public string Token { get; set; }
 }
```

When RestSharp deserializes the XML into an instance of TokenResponse, the 'Result' property is being correctly set; however, the 'Token' property is set to null. I have verified that the XML response has the data set to some token string value before deserialization. How do I correctly set the 'Token' property to the value of the 'data' XML element?

Furthermore, when changing the name of the 'Token' property to 'Value' the value is set to "trueTokenStringValueHere" when the above XML response is received.

Comment: show your deserialization code

Comment: @BalajiMarimuthu RestSharp deserializes the response automatically, the only property I set for deserialization is 'XmlSerializer' on the RestSharp RestRequest object. The related code: `request.XmlSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.DotNetXmlSerializer();`